# Rest transfer non serializable objects

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization, binary

Is there a way to send a non serializable object via Rest ?
I have a request class where some properies can be serialized, but not all.

The class inherits a other class from a SDK (see below 'IWorkflowContext'). This class is protected and can not be serialized - but needs to be transfered. I tried to use JSON, where the non serialization of the SDK object is an issue, when I try to serialize it binary I get a serializer exception

> "Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed."

My request & serialization looks like this for binary :

```
byte[] bytes;
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
{
    formatter.Serialize(s, userRequest);
    bytes = s.ToArray();
}
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

And here the Json Serialization

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(userRequest.GetType());
ser.WriteObject(stream, userRequest);
```

Or another Json serializers (results in the same non serialization problem)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

For reference is here my class (modified for binary serialization - for Json I had for each property a Datamember flag.

```
 [Serializable()]
    public class AzureRequest
    {
        public string _orgaName = string.Empty;
        public string _connectionString = string.Empty;

        public IWorkflowContext _contextWorkflow = null;
        public string _webhookOperation = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Connectionrequest describes a schema to connect to a CRM.
        /// e.g. "Url=http://OrgName.crm.dynamics.com/OrgName;AuthType=Office365;Username=UserName@OrgName.onmicrosoft.com;Password=Password";
        /// </summary>
         public string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return _connectionString;
            }
            set
            {
                _connectionString = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Organization Name of the CRM to contact
        /// </summary>
        public string OrgaName
        {
            get
            {
                return _orgaName;
            }
            set
            {
                _orgaName = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Is the running Context for the Worklfow instance
        /// </summary>
        public IWorkflowContext ContextWorkflow
        {
            get
            {
                return _contextWorkflow;
            }
            set
            {
                _contextWorkflow = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Operation, the Webhook should perform
        /// </summary>
        public string WebhookOperation
        {
            get
            {
                return _webhookOperation;
            }
            set
            {
                _webhookOperation = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried two different serializers - they are not directly in the code - one is commented ( I will edit the post - thanks )

Comment: When you *know* the structure of your classes - why don't you make your own serializer? That would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: It contains more subclasses and references & so on. 
The SDK is available on both sides ( sender and receiver of the request ), but the serialization is not possible of this object.

Comment: Why not create a [`DTO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) for the non-serializable type?  If you use the data contract serializer you can replace the original with the DTO using [surrogates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates).  With Json.NET, you can do the replacement in a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).